# Restoring stdout after using dup

Tags: c, stdout, dup2

Using `fork` I created a child and in the child I'm executing the `ls` command using `execl`. To send the output to parent,I used `pipe` and `dup`. The parent then prints the output. The code gives the expected output, but when I tried to restore back the `stdout` which I saved initially in `stdout_holder`, nothing is printed on terminal (when I used printf("hello") or the execl statement below it).
However after few observations, it is observed that `hello` is printed only when nothing is done after redirecting "1" for the first time. (If I don't do anything after `dup(fd[1],1)` and simply do `dup(stdout_holder,1)` )
Why is this happening?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
 {int fd[2],stdout_holder;
 char str;
 pid_t pid;
 pipe(fd);
 pid=fork();
 if(pid==0)
  { stdout_holder=dup(1);
    close(fd[0]);
   printf("stdout_holder=%d\n",stdout_holder); 
   fd[1]=dup2(fd[1],1);
   execl("/bin/ls","ls","-l",NULL);
   stdout_holder=dup2(stdout_holder,1);
   printf("hello\n"); //Terminal doesnt show output.
   execl("/bin/ls","ls","-l",NULL); //Terminal doesnt show output

 }
else
 { close(fd[1]);
   wait(&pid);
   while(read(fd[0],&str,1)>0)
   printf("%c",str);
  } 
}
```

Comment: execl() does _not_ return on success, but replaces the process image. You have to fork().

Answer (score 2):

As in line 63 of [this file](https://github.com/pouyanh/isolated-iostream/blob/master/src/main.c#L63) you should save stdout file descriptor before changing it:

```
int moutfd = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);

// Do the going-to-be-buffered jobs

dup2(moutfd, STDOUT_FILENO);
close(moutfd);
close(fd);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues:

1. `execl()` does not return (except if there is an error), you need to `fork()` again or use e.g. system().
   On `execl` the buffers are not emptied automatically, so
   the printf output does (at least for me) not reach stdout.
2. The first output of `printf("stdout_holder= ...` and `ls` goes directly to stdout, not
   through the pipe (stdout is not replaced). You would
   need to use `dup2()` at the first place or `close(1)` before the `dup()` call..

Comment: Thank you :) regarding your second issue(according to what i read and tried), the ls after the printf  doesnt go to stdout because dup2 closes the "1" automatically...dup2(fd1,fd2) ..when this is called ,if fd2 is a file descriptor of a file which is open, it automatically closes it(so close(1) is not needed)..thts why the ls went to pipe and i got the output when i printed in parent process.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you place a call to the execl(execv, execlp, etc.), it starts the execution of a new program (creates a new process image). The execution of this new program causes the process to forget all about its previous process image. The execl function does not return to the same process image unless it encounters some error.

```
if(pid==0)
  { stdout_holder=dup(1);
    close(fd[0]);
   printf("stdout_holder=%d\n",stdout_holder); 
   fd[1]=dup2(fd[1],1);
   execl("/bin/ls","ls","-l",NULL); //creates a new process image
   //will never reach here unless there is an error in the execl call
   stdout_holder=dup2(stdout_holder,1);//Line 7
   printf("hello\n");
   execl("/bin/ls","ls","-l",NULL);// Line 9
 }
```

After the child process finishes the first execl call, it will terminate, and hence will never reach the remaining code (from line 7 to line 9). Executing a new process image completely changes the contents of the memory, copying only the argument and environment strings to the new locations.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank uu :) i m actually trying to see a example of restoring the stdout...if i replace the execl statement with printf statements (say 2)..they are neither redirected to pipe nor getting printed on the terminal..after i restore the stdout and give one printf statement all the statements appear on the terminal (the 2 previous ones and one given now)..i guess redirecting printf ' s output has a issue..?
Thank u so much :)

edit : sorry my bad...i forgot commenting out the printing portion in parent process which printed the previous statements.